# How can I quickly get to a set of commonly used files?

Tags: file

I tend to edit particular text files much more often than others. There might be 30 or 40 or so different files I tend to edit most often. Plus there are others that kind of rotate in and out as things I am temporarily working on. Even though I might infrequently edit them, during periods of work involving that file I might frequently access the file many times over a short time period, say a week.

**The problem is how to open these files quickly in Vim.**

Currently I generally just type `:e` then manually type in the full path in the command line which is pretty tedious. Also, if I don't remember the path, then I end up either leaving Vim altogether and going to Caja to find the file, or using `:Sex`.

The only shortcuts I currently use is that I have about 10 aliases for going to particular directories. So, for example, if I am working on a project where several needed files will be in a commonly used directory, then I use the alias to change to there, then open Vim. After that, I don't need to type the full path. I just have to enter the file name. However, this method only works for directories where I have big projects going, which is only a few of them. Most of the files I edit are in one off places. Also, I don't want to try to remember 50 different aliases. I have a hard enough time just remembering the 10 I already have.

What I would really like would be a hotlist of my most commonly used files with a numeric or alphabetic key. So, I could, for example, press a hotkey and a multi-column list comes up of my favorite files. Then I would press, say, 'C' to open the file keyed as 'C' or whatever. That would allow me to open any of my favorite files in 2 keystrokes, which would be the ideal.

Comment: There are a lot of plugins that do fuzzy file find on your filesystem (+ added things like most recently used files, buffers, etc) -- maybe those would suit you? For example https://github.com/habamax/vim-select
Otherwise you can implement your own "commonly used files" popup window...

Comment: or maybe `:browse old` would help you a bit too

Comment: If you're open to install [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf), then I explain in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67019648/14467607) how to configure it to search a particular subset of directories on your system. This effectively means I can always find my most commonly edited files in about 5 keystrokes.

Comment: @MaximKim That is useful, but there seems to be no easy way to either sort or search that list.

Comment: @mattb That is a useful tool, however, I have a big directory system so searching through the whole thing can be time consuming.

Comment: @TylerDurden, indeed. That is why there is so many plugins targeting this. You can DIY one, as I did for myself https://github.com/habamax/.vim#fuzzy-popup-finder

Answer (score 1):

There are countless possibilities using plugins and VimScript'ing. But let's focus on "built-in stuff" only.

- **cdpath** instead of 10 aliases for going to directories

This is an option that works much like one in `/bin/sh`. That is, if you have `set cdpath=/some/where,/else` then instead of typing `:cd /some/where/dirname` you can type just `:cd dirname`.

- **marks** for remembering up to 26 files plus last file from previous Vim run

To open the last file being edited press <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>. This should work out-of-the-box provided that `:h viminfo` file was loaded properly. The bookmarks "0"-"9" are auto written into it.

Press `mA` - `mZ` to set global marks. Press <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to go to mark "A" as usual. The global marks keep both line/column number and file name. And they persist across Vim runs, as they are also stored into viminfo file automatically. Use `:marks A-Z` to see their values.

- **oldfiles** builtin MRU file list

This is also restored from viminfo. `:oldfiles` to browse through the list. `:e#<42` to open file #42 from it. (BTW. Any command could be typed right from `:h hit-enter-prompt`, i.e. while still having that list before your eyes).

- **find** to search for file through the directory list

The option `:h 'path'` is often used as buffer-local to support `gf` command and such. But there's no rule against using it globally. Do `:set path=/dir1/dir2` and then you may `:find foobar.txt` instead of usual and longer `:edit /dir1/dir2/foobar.txt`.

You can also force searching through the whole subtree by `:set path=/dir1/**`. Though it could result in a great deal of disk I/O.

BTW. Plain `:edit` also supports `:h starstar`, so this could even work `:e /dir1/**/foobar.txt`. Unless `E77: Too many file names` happens when there is more than one `foobar.txt` sitting under `/dir1`.

Comment: Generally I recommend against using `:find` as a fuzzy finder because it requires setting `path`, which is used for things like `gf` and many many other commands

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Yes, and I mentioned this too. But personal preferences may vary much.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use a combination of:

- Mru plugin https://github.com/yegappan/mru.
- Leaderf mru capabilities for fuzzy searching
- save bookmark for files. What you asked for, really. I open bookmarks and start linewise search with easymotion. https://github.com/ipod825/vim-bookmark
- a set of helper functions to track recent directories via fzf
- vim-ctrlspace (workspaces)